# '&&' operator in Javascript vs in Java

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I am currently reading JavaScript from *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide*. On page 76, there is this statement written,

```
o && o.x // => 1: o is truthy, so return value of o.x
```

Being a Java programmer I want to ask, why is it returning 1 instead of `'true'` In Java this was not the case, but anyway I know JavaScript is different but the Logical AND mechanism is the same everywhere.(In C it returns 1 as true.)

I am asking is, why does it makes sense for this behavior at all?
Is there any way, I can ensure to return only the true or false values?

Comment: you can use `!!(o && o.x)`

Comment: This is called _short-circuiting_ in javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the Spec for [Binary Logical Operators](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-binary-logical-operators)

> The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type
>   Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two
>   operand expressions.

This is a feature used in javascript a lot, one common use case is to assign a default value to a variable if it is not defined. Like assume you are expecting a options object as a param but is not mandatory so the user may not pass it

```
function x(options){
    options = options || {};
    //now your can access optionx.a without fearing whether options is undefined
}
```

You can do something like `!!(o && o.x)` to always get a true/false

Answer (score 4):

if we have:

```
expr1 && expr2
```

&& Returns 'expr1' if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns 'expr2'. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

So if we have:

`Var xyz = a && b;` //where a is undefined(false) and b is 123, then it will allocate undefined.

In case of if statements, these values are specifically converted to boolean.

Refer the following link: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Boolean(o && o.x);` to get `true` or `false`

Comment: better yet, use coercion: `!!(o && o.x)`

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the value of the right operand. If the value of `o.x` was `true`, it would return `true`. If the value of `o.x` was `'banana'`, it would return `'banana'`.

```js
var o = {x:true};
console.log(o && o.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically `&&` operator implemented to return the first operand if it's value is not zero, and returns the second operand otherwise in a lot of languages including Java, C/C++, Javascript, Perl...
While most of the languages accepts any type of operands, Java forces you to use boolean operands so it always returns true or false. 
In order to force a boolean result in Javascript use:

```
Boolean(a && b)
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is called **coercion**. Coercion is the action of forcing an object to behave like other type, and the logical operators can produce **coercion** when trying to access the value of the object to be evaluated.

It is important to remember the table for **truthy** and **falsy** values, because due to coercion, different results can be obtained.

- `false`       produces `false`
- `0`           produces `false`
- `“”`          produces `false`
- `NaN`         produces `false`
- `null`        produces `false`
- `undefined`   produces `false`

Everything else produces `true`, including the text `"0"` and `"false"`, functions, arrays and empty objects.

Given the rules for logic operators, exists **short-circuit** evaluation in JavaScript, e.g:

```js
0 && 1; //-> 0, falsy value
!(0 && 1); //-> true, falsy value negated
!!(0 && 1); //-> false, boolean falsy value

void 0 && alert("1") //-> undefined (void produces undefined)
[] && Math.ceil(9.1) //-> 10, truthy value
{} && someFunc() //-> the result of someFunc()

0 || null; //-> null, falsy value
null || "0"; //-> "0", truthy value
"" || void 1; //-> undefined, falsy value
!!(+"5px" || {}); //-> true, boolean truthy value
```

Coercion is useful when you have to validate default values, in order to prevent errors, e.g.

```js
function divide (a, b) {
    a = +a; //-> coerced to number
    b = +b; //-> coerced to number
    if (!a) return 0; //-> NaN or zero
    return b && a / b; //-> b must be a number different from zero
}

divide(); //-> 0
divide(5); //-> NaN, no error thrown!
divide(5, "a"); //-> NaN, no error thrown!
divide(5, 0); //-> 0, division by zero prevented!
divide(49, 6); //-> 8.1666
```

If you want to prevent returning `NaN`, just add another coercion in the return statement:

```js
return (b && a / b) || 0;
```

You can check other coercion cases: [JavaScript Coercion](https://gist.github.com/jherax/9ac4d1602d30882f8cb0)

---

*Happy coding!*

Comment: I already knew _how_ this work, but no one of these terms. Anytime is a good time to learn. :-) +1